# Angular - Binding to string array at index

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular (5.x) and I am trying to bind the input value to string array (`rule.values`) at index (`i`) but when I change the input the array values do not change so I think binding fails. I appreciate any help or hint. Thank you

```
<div *ngFor="let _ of rule.value; let i = index;" id="values">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      Value #{{(i + 1).toString()}}
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="values{{i}}" [ngModel]="rule.value[i]" name="values{{i}}" required>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="rule.value.splice(i, 1)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would it change. You only use one-way binding. Not two-way binding. https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when I change the input the array values do not change

You've only specified that whatever is in the model should reflected to the view by using `[ngModel]="rule.value[i]"`. `[]` brackets show the "model -> view" relationship.

If you want to "catch" the value changes from the view to model, then you need to use the `()` brackets, too.

```
[(ngModel)]="rule.value[i]
```

This is a so-called "banana in the box" syntax since the `(` resembles a banana and a `[]` is a box.

Using `[]` and `()` at the same time like this is basically a shortcut for writing both "model -> view" and "view -> model" bindings.
The full version of the above code would be:

```
[ngModel]="rule.value[i]"
(ngModelChange)="rule.value[i] = $event"
```

---

By the way:

```
Value #{{(i + 1).toString()}}
```

You do not need to call `.toString()`, everything is automatically cast to a string when interpolated in a template.

Comment: When I type the inputs, I think it keeps refreshing the DOM and I can only type one character at a time

Comment: Add `; trackBy: trackByIndex` after `let i = index` in template (`*ngFor` part) and in your `.ts` file add a method `trackByIndex (index: number) { return index }`. This will stop the flicker you're experiencing.

Comment: No problems! Just a friendly reminder to accept the answer if it's what you were looking for -- it helps other see it as a correct solution.